# FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`

Tags: numpy, future-warning

```
In [57]: dW = np.zeros((2,2), int)                                              

In [58]: x = [[0,1,1,0,1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]                               

In [59]: np.add.at(dW,x,1)                                                      
/home/infinity/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
```

I was trying to create a confusion matrix using numpy, but I got the previous error. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we supply an array rather than a list, we don't get the future warning:

```
In [11]: In [57]: dW = np.zeros((2,2), int)
    ...: 
    ...: In [58]: x = [[0,1,1,0,1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
In [12]: dW
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
In [13]: x
Out[13]: [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
In [14]: np.add.at(dW,np.array(x),1)
In [15]: dW
Out[15]: 
array([[5, 5],
       [7, 7]])
```

According to the docs,

> indices : array_like or tuple
> Array like index object or slice object for indexing into first
> operand. If first operand has multiple dimensions, indices can be a
> tuple of array like index objects or slice objects.

```
In [17]: np.add.at(dW,tuple(x),1)
In [18]: dW
Out[18]: 
array([[6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
In [19]: tuple(x)
Out[19]: ([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Recent `numpy` versions have been tightening the indexing rules.  In the past lists were sometimes allowed in contexts that really expected tuples or arrays.  This futurewarning is part of that tightening.

===

As commented:

```
In [22]: In [57]: dW = np.zeros((2,2), int)
    ...: 
In [23]: np.add.at(dW,tuple(x),1)
In [24]: dW
Out[24]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Just saying : There will be a difference with `dW` if you use `tuple()` or `numpy.array()`.